# How to run Scala code in SBT Build.scala just before compile of Scala files?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to run some Scala code, just for the moment to println out "Hello", but I wish to run the Scala code just before compile of Scala code in SBT project. I found that in build.sbt the following works.

```
compile in Compile <<= compile in Compile map {
  comp => {
    println("Hello")
  }
  comp
}
```

However I wish to do it within Build.scala, how can I do it in Build.scala?

Comment: As long as you `import sbt._` and `import Keys._`, you should be able to use exactly that same code in a `Build.scala`. That said, you use `dependsOn` instead of `map`: `<<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(Def.task { println("Hello") })`

Comment: @sjrd Why don't you make the comment an answer?

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Good point. Done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you import the usual:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
```

you should be able to use exactly that same code in a `Build.scala`.

That being said, you should use `dependsOn` instead of `map`:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile).dependsOn(Def.task {
  println("Hello")
})
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `map` work here? I'd say that `map` is after the task it maps over while `dependsOn` makes the dependency vice versa.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski the OP asked for code running *before* the compile task. `map` makes it execute after. `dependsOn` executes it before.

Comment: Right. Sorry for my confusion.